# Open, read and write by writing to new file

Tags: c, linux

I have recently begun C and want to open a file, read the content of the file and then write to new file while adding in `connector` words inside the `{}` of the text.

However, I am not so sure whether I am getting the set-up for `open/read` correctly.

For example:

```
#define MAX_READ 20
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
   
    char buffer[MAX_READ + 1];
    ssize_t numRead;  
    char connector[2] = ["and", "or"];

    if(argc > 1){
        int file = open(argv[1], O_RDWR);
        if(file == -1){
            perror("open");
            exit(1);
        }
        numRead = read(file, buffer, MAX_READ)
        if(numRead == -1){
            perror("read");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my sample text:

```
I am running {} swimming together with my friend {} brother
```

Expected output:

1. Open the file contents
2. Read the files content into a variable; match `{}` and replace each by the connector.
3. Write the result to a NEW file.

Output:

```
I am running and swimming together with my friend or brother
```

Comment: What is `func` supposed to do? Why does it call `main`? While it's allowed in C, it's considered bad.

Comment: You'll have to create a new file, with the inserted words.

Comment: And what have your C text-books or tutorials told you about characters and strings? How many characters can you have in a single-character literal (using single quotes like `'`)?

Comment: The buffer isn't large enough to hold the sample text you have shown, and there is no loop either.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for noticing; my python background tends to kick in and I forget to stick with `"`. `func`  was supposed rto be called within `main` to access the `argc/argv` to get the text files`.

Comment: What is the desired output? Please [edit] the question and tell us more. Clearly state the contents of your input file(s), the desired contend of the output file(s) and the way you invoke your program. BTW remove your `func` function, it's pointless, it will never be called.

Comment: @Jabberwocky updated as requested -- however, not sure as to whether `read` can work in this case it reads the files in bytes, unless I can decode the bytes into `utf-8` ?

Comment: @dollarbillion forget UTF-8 at that stage of your project. `read` deals only with raw bytes. If you need to deal with UTF-8 it's a very different story.

Comment: @dollarbillion the problem statement is still not clear. What happens if your input file contails more than two pairs of `{}`, like for example: `foo {} bar {} foobar {} barfoo`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky For this particular case its has only two curl braces to match with the total number of connectors. Otherwise, we repeat the iteration by creating an empty list with `n-1` length and populating it recursively with `and/or` by the number of matched curly braces. I can see how this is done with python, just very unfamiliar with `C` but looks like a strong first project for me.

Comment: Get in the habit now of *not* *doing* *that*.  Do not "update" files.  Do not modify files.  Think of files as immutable objects.  Open one file for reading, and another for writing.  When you are done, rename the output file to have the name of the original input file.  Your chances of data corruption are greatly minimized, and it is a lot easier to write the code.

Comment: @WilliamPursell That does sound less error prone thank you, I will keep this in mind.

Comment: @dollarbillion please make that clear __in the question__. All information concerning the question should be in the question and not scattered in comments. [Edit] the question.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you! I have updated the post In the meantime I will test a solution based on these updates

Comment: It's still unclear what should happen if you have more than 2 pairs of {} in the input file.

Comment: What is `char connector[2] = ["and", "or"];` supposed to be?  Did you intend `char *connector [2] = { "and", "or" };`?

Comment: Why are you using `open` instead of `fopen`?  `fopen` is in the language, `open` only exists in sub-dialects.  `fopen` is much easier to use and a beginner would be well advised to stick with the higher level abstraction it provides.